# How to remove specific columns from a list of dataframes when all of these columns do not exist in each dataframe

Tags: r

Here is a sample dataset:

```
dat1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, des.1 = 4:6, x = 7:9, not = 10:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
dat2 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, descript = 4:6, y = 7:9, yes = 10:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
dat3 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, description = 4:6, x = 7:9, X4 = 10:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
dat_list <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3)
```

For example, If I wanted to remove all columns named x and X4 across this list of dataframes, I could do this - accessing each dataframe that contain these columns and removing them like so:

```
dat_list[[1]] <- dat_list[[1]] %>% select(-x)
dat_list[[3]] <- dat_list[[3]] %>% select(-c("x", "X4"))
```

However I'm wondering if there is a way of doing this across the list as a whole - bearing in mind that some of these columns will not exist in each dataframe within the list.

Can anyone think of a way that you could remove all columns named c("x", "X4") across all dataframes in this list?

Comment: Try `lapply(dat_list, function(i)i[!names(i) %in% c('x', 'X4')])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one approach is:

```
library(tidyverse)
map(dat_list, function(xx) xx %>% select(any_of(c("x", "X4"))))
# [[1]]
#   x
# 1 7
# 2 8
# 3 9

# [[2]]
# data frame with 0 columns and 3 rows

# [[3]]
#   x X4
# 1 7 10
# 2 8 11
# 3 9 12
```

Comment: This is the approach I would take, though since the OP wants all columns *except* "x" and "X4", you would need to put an exclamation mark before the `any_of()`:
```select(!any_of(c("x", "X4")))```

Comment: ah i missed that, good spot!